# OpenMP target (update) into

Tags: c++, openmp, hpc, xeon-phi, offloading

I am working with OpenMP 4.5 Accelerator Model on platform equipped with Intel Xeon Phi coprorcessors. I would like to use CPU + MIC to joint problem solving. I need use mechanism similar to Intel Offload into. I would like to transfer immediately data from buffer A from card to buffer B. Example of this is presented on code bellow.

```
#pragma offload target(mic : 0) \
   out(A[0:size] : REUSE into(B[0:size]) 
{ }
```

I would like to do it using OpenMP Accelerator Model. It is possible?

Comment: Not super familiar with MIC programming, but my best guess is you're looking for